# is it possible to use node js Postgres client in blocking / synchronous way

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am looking for a node js client to connect to PostgreSQL 8.3 and run my queries in synchronous blocking mode (for scripting not web server).

I am currently using https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres
which works well but it only supports async.

Thank you,

Sean.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you need is to learn to deal with asynchronous programming. [Promises may help you](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#what-are-promises-and-why-should-i-use-them).

Comment: I program in Async all the time, but sometimes you want a quick dirty script and sync is a better simpler approach ...

Comment: If you feel the need to look for a different driver just for that, you're doing async wrong and I guess you don't use promises. A clean driver shouldn't block.

Comment: Unrelated but: Postgres 8.3 is end-of-life and no longer supported. You should upgrade to a supported versoin (9.x)

Comment: What are your queries and why do you have to call all of them from nodejs?  You could wrap multiple queries in one ore more sub stored functions and from nodejs call a master stored function that calls all the subs. That way you have one nodejs call and many query executions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use async in series mode to run your queries in a sync way and to avoid multiple callbacks struture : [Async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)

```
pg.connect(configDB.connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }

    var condition = true;
    async.series([
        CreateExtensions,
        PushSQL,
        function (next) {
            if (condition) {
                UpdateTable(id, name, next);
            }
            else {
                next();
            }
        }
    ],
    function(err, results) {
        if (err) { console.error(err); }
        client.end();
        pg.end();
    });

    function CreateExtensions(callback)  {
        var queryConfig = 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis; CREATE EXTENSION hstore;';
        client.query(queryConfig, function(err) {
            return callback(err);
        });
    }

    function PushSQL(callback)  {
        var queryConfig = fs.readFileSync("./database/cmdb.sql", 'utf8');
        client.query(queryConfig, function(err) {
            return callback(err);
        });
    }

    function UpdateTable(id, name, callback) {
        var queryConfig = "UPDATE table SET name = '" + name + "' WHERE id = " + id + ";";
        client.query(queryConfig, function(err) {
            condition = false;
            return callback(err);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thank for the comment, but, what if you wanted to put a conditional statement inside one of the functions, such as: if (something) do another SQL select query, you would not be able to put it in the outside main async.series right? and your code once again will become a pyramid, right?    Again I am very familair with async programming, but sometimes looking for a quick non web server type scripting where sync would be ideal

Comment: To resolve your problem I add an example with a conditional statement in async.series. You can also use an anonymous function like my example to pass parameters to the query function.

Comment: tx for the reply, but how would you pass the variable 'condition' to  function (next) { ? as it is not in the same scope as let's say PushSQL... you would need to declare a global variable condition or at least a high up in the stack variable... right?

Comment: Yes you can use variable in the scope of pg.connect (I add a variable in my example). Also, if you want to pass parameters one function to an other in async.series, you can use async.waterfall instead.